# Can I add more than one override method in a constructor in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, overriding

Like in the below example, I added two overrides methods build() & buildAdd() in the constructor. So can this be done.

```
public class createData {
    ...
    public createData(DataAdd dataAdd){
        super(dataAdd);
        build();
        buildAdd(); 
      }
    @Override
    public void build(){
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public void buildAdd(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not even a question mark in your text

Comment: Voting to close, the question is unclear (there is not even any).

Comment: As it's written, that's going to fail to compile because it doesn't extend a class whose methods include `build()` and `buildAdd()`. If it did, there'd be no problem. You could always try to compile it and see what happens.

Comment: Did you try it? This type of question can be resolved by experimenting, instead of asking here. Be aware though that calling overridable methods from a constructor is asking for problems if some other class inherits your class, overrides these methods and relies on data that wasn't yet initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your class `createData` (class names in Java should be capitalised by the way) extends some other class right?

To make it clear, you're not adding overrides in the constructor, you're adding overrides in the class and calling them from the constructor.

So yes, you can do that, you can even do:

```
public class GenericCreateData
{
  public GenericCreateData(DataAdd dataAdd)
  {
    ...
    build();
    buildAdd();
  }

  public void build()
  {
    System.out.println("genericBuild");
  }

  public void buildAdd()
  {
    System.out.println("genericBuildAdd");
  }
}
```

```
public class SpecificCreateData extends GenericCreateData
{
  public SpecificCreateData(DataAdd dataAdd)
  {
    super(dataAdd);
  }

  @Override
  public void build()
  {
    System.out.println("specificBuild");
  }

  @Override
  public void buildAdd()
  {
    System.out.println("specificBuildAdd");
  }
}
```

calling `new GenericCreateData(dataAdd)` will output:

```
genericBuild
genericBuildAdd
```

calling `new SpecificCreateData(dataAdd)` will output:

```
specificBuild
specificBuildData
```

Since methods are called on the specific instance type

Comment: yes, my createData class extend some other class. Thanks for detail explanations.